# How do I use Declarative Services with an Eclipse Equinox Launcher application?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox, declarative-services

The project I am working on is launched as an Eclipse PDE product, running the main class (let's call it `MainClass` for discussion sake) which implements the `IApplication` interface.

I am trying to use Declarative Services to bind my references to my service bundles. This works, in that the references are bound at startup in an instance of `MainClass`.

However, despite any configuration settings in the plugin and bundle such as `cardinality` and `singleton`, the Eclipse Launcher creates a new instance of `MainClass` and does not bind the services.

While I could store the references in a static variable when it is first bound, I am trying to avoid a messy 'hack' like this.

Is there any way to force the Launcher to use the existing instance of `MainClass` that was already created by the Declarative Services? Or is there some other solution to this problem, without getting rid of Eclipse PDE Launcher?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Thank you for the response. It looks like the Eclipse PDE Launcher is probably the wrong approach for this project anyways; now I just have to find a different solution and convince the rest of my team.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. The fundamental problem is that Eclipse never comprehensively embraced OSGi Services. They moved somewhat in that direction with Eclipse 4, but unfortunately `IApplication` predates that and is from the Extension Registry world.